# Store file to documentDirectory without user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So currently I have an app where the user can store a json file in the Shortcuts folder on the device. The current code I am running looks like this:

```
func saveDataToDocuments(_ data: Data, jsonFilename: String = "Userfile.JSON") {

    let jsonFileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(jsonFilename)
    do {
        try data.write(to: jsonFileURL)
        print(jsonFileURL)
        
        let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        
        try? data.write(to: jsonFileURL)
        let exportMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(url: jsonFileURL, in: .exportToService)
        
        exportMenu.delegate = self
        exportMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        
        present(exportMenu, animated: true)
        
    } catch {
        print("Error:= \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

The file is created and contains data that the user has created in the app, and each time the user edit the data, he/she has to manually save the file again. So what I am asking is: Is it possible to make a function that after the user has saved the file one time, the user can now just tap a button "Update file", and the file get's saved and replaced automatically in the background, without the user having to open up the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and tap Archive and Replace?

Comment: Get your old file using the file name then delete the old file and replace it with a new one

Comment: @teja_D Could you provide an example? I know how to replace the file using the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, but I want it to be done silent(in the background).

Comment: Do you need to save the file outside the app's sandbox? That is why you are using UIDocumentPickerViewController, correct?

Comment: @teja_D Yes, that is correct, because I want the Shortcut's app to be able to read the data in the file.

Comment: Ohk! In that case, there is no way to implement it in the background because iOS will not allow you to write something outside the app's sandbox without user's knowledge